# Input/Output connectors causing Modelica model to be unbalanced

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'm building a custom fluid model to eventually allow for a 3-dimensional velocity. I've designed the equations such that the model runs with the following boundary conditions:

```
  pressure_out = 500000;
  hin=3000e3;
   mdot[1] = 66.3;
```

The inlet pressure, outlet enthalpy, and outlet mass flow rates should then all be calculated via the model. I then put in an outlet connector (standard Modelica fluid port named Outlet):

```
     Outlet.m_flow + mdot[3]=0;
     Outlet.p = pressure_out;
     Outlet.h_outflow = hout;
```

and correspondingly remove the boundary condition for pressure_out so that:

```
  hin=3000e3;
  mdot[1] = 66.3;
```

and the model is still balanced. However, once I add in the Inlet connector and set its connections:

```
     Inlet.m_flow =mdot[1];
     Inlet.p = pressure_in;
     Inlet.h_outflow = hin;
```

I remove the boundary conditions because the model *should* be capable of being informed of a pressure, mass flow rate, and enthalpy. However, when I remove my boundary conditions the model believes that I'm missing an equation. I cannot for the life of me figure out what to do. If I re-add in any of the initial boundary conditions, the model breaks because a boundary is singularly over-determined. 
In summary,

```
 pout = 500000; replaced by  Outlet.p = pout;
 hout = states[2].h; add Outlet.h_outflow = hout;
 p[1] = pin; add Inlet.p = pin;
 hin=3000e3; replaced by Inlet.h_outflow = hin;
 mdot[1] = 66.3; replaced by Inlet.m_flow = mdot[1];
```

I've tried using inStream for the flow variables, I've tried bypassing my internal variables, and I've tried each port one at a time. The Inlet port is unhappy, and I'm at a loss as far as why it is.

Comment: Update: the model is now balanced and working. However, the solution (to me) is odd. At the Inlet, I have to say the following: hin = inStream(Inlet.h_outflow); hin = Inlet.h_outflow. However, on the outlet side, it's only hout = Outlet.h_outflow. If I either take away the inlet instream() or add an outlet instream(), the model is no longer balanced. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As you point out yourself, the problem lies in the usage of `stream` connectors. When you use `stream` connectors in a model it must always provide a value of the outflowing `stream` variable for each connector. That is, in your case you need an expression of the outflowing enthalpy of each connector.

This [Github Wiki page](https://github.com/justnielsen/ModelicaTutorials/wiki/Stream-connectors) might be helpful to you

Best regards,

Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: Rene, I'm still confused then as to why my "outlet" connections fail if I have both the direct equating and inStream(), and why the "inlet" connections fail if I only have one of the two. It (somewhat) makes sense to me if the model assumes that flow goes from 1-->2, but shouldn't both sides be defined in the same manner in case flow reverses?